# DB authentication with SQL Server, ASP MVC4 and AngularJS

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, angularjs, asp.net-web-api

I have WebAPI service with C# api for it. And it works fine with impersonation.

I added MVC4 + AngularJS front-end for this service. It displays user login on a page without problem (NTLM).

In Web API controller I've added DB repository for some routines and I'm trying to call this controller via AngularJS.

And I'm getting an error:

> An error has occurred.
>   Login failed for user 'NT AUTHORITY\ANONYMOUS LOGON'.

Mu auth settings for site (local IIS) is Windows (only)

Comment: How do you know the WebApi project works fine for impersonation? How did you test it? And how are you calling the WebApi form your MVC front end?

Comment: ` It displays user login on a page without problem (NTLM).` You can't do delegation across NTLM, you'll need Kerberos and delegation setup for this.